# Which EIP to use: retrieve config by message content, mapping, filtering and OAuth then send, retry only send part

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to Camel, and my use case is as such:

- We receive messages from AMQ, and we want to remap this message, and sends this message to different endpoints of customer
- each customer has config of what fields to include, and urls of OAuth + url to send message(REST apis) + credentials
- Customers are grouped under agents, one agent can dominate several customers. We have config in a Map, organized by "agentId" as key, and list of "customerConfigs" as value.
- By one field in the message, we decide which agent this message should send to
- And then, we iterate all customers under that agent, checking what fields each one need, and remap message accordingly
- We also filter by checking if the message content meets customer's criteria. If yes, we do OAuth against the OAuth url of that customer, and send message to them. If not, skip.

We are doing it with Camel, and by now, all steps from receiving to mapping and retrieving configs and so on, is defined in a bean.(`.bean(GeneralBean.class)`). It works.

But now, we want to retry against customer endpoints, and I decide to separate steps into several Camel steps, because I don't want to retry the whole receiving/remapping/retrieving configs like now. I just want to retry last step, which is sending.

Now comes the question: which Camel component should I use?

1. I think [recipient list](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/recipientList-eip.html) is good, but not sure how. Maybe "Dynamic router" is better?
2. When defining steps, when I am retrieving the config of each customer, one object in the exchange body(let's call it `RemappedMessage`) becomes two (`RemappedMessage` and a list of `CustomerConfig`). They have one to many relationship. How do I pass down these two objects to next bean? Or should I process them together in one bean? In the `Exchange`? In `@ExchangeProperties Map<String, Object> properties`? The latter works, but IMO is not very Camel. Or define a tuple class to combine them? I use it a lot but think it's ugly.
3. I don't think there is some syntax in Camel to get some properties of object in the Exchange and put it into the `to()` as url and as basic credentials username and password?

In general, I want to divide the process into several steps in a Camel pipeline, but not sure how to deal with "one object split into more objects and they need to go hand in hand to downstream" problem.

I am not using Spring, but Quarkus.

Now, I am with:

```java
        from("activemq:queue:" + appConfig.getQueueName())
                .bean(IncomingMessageConverter.class) // use class form so that Camel will cache the bean
                .bean(UserIdValidator.class) // validate and if wrong, end route here
                .bean(CustomerConfigRetrieverBean.class) // retrieve config of customer, by agent id. How to pass down both??
                .bean(EndpointFieldsTailor.class) // remove fields if this customer is not interested. Needs CustomerConfig
                .recipientList(xxxxxx) // how?
                // what's next?
```

Because `RemappedMessage` is the return type of the step  `.bean(IncomingMessageConverter.class)`, afterwards Camel can bind args to it so I can have access to the mapped message. But obviously I cannot return 2 objects together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recipient List is ideal when you want to send the same message to multiple endpoints and you know what those endpoints are before entering the Recipient List.

The Dynamic Router can route messages to a number of endpoints, the list and order of which not necessarily known at the time the router is entered. Since you have a one-to-many situation, Dynamic Router may be a better fit.

A simpler approach that might work is to prepare a List of tuples. Each tuple would contain a `CustomerConfig` and a `RemappedMessage`. You would then [split](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/split-eip.html) the list and in the splitter send the message to the agent. For the tuple you could use something like [ImmutablePair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html), a `Map`, or just a two-element `List`.

As for setting a url and username/password, I'll assume you're using Camel's HTTP component. It's probably best to provide these values as headers since the http component allows this. The URL can be set with the [CamelHttpUri](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/http-component.html#_endpoint_header_CamelHttpUri) header. And the HTTP component will generally pass message headers as HTTP headers, so you can set things like the `Authorization` header just by setting a message header with the same name.

And there's definitely support for setting headers from values in the exchange and message. E.g.

```
// assumes the body is a List in which the first element is a CustomerConfig
.setHeader("Authorization", simple("${body[0].authValue}"))
```

In reality, you'll probably have to do a little bit more work for authorization. E.g, if it's basic auth, you'll have to compute the value you want to use. I'd set that in a header or property and then refer to it like:

```
.setHeader("Authorization", simple("${header.basicAuthValue}"))
// or
.setHeader("Authorization", simple("${exchangeProperty.basicAuthValue}"))
```

Comment: OK at last I use a bean for this kind of Camel HTTP config. The config is too complicated. See my answer.

Comment: Much appreciated! Directed me to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

At last the route looks very complicated, but each bean only does one thing.

```java
// main route, split to direct:split root and return aggregated list of EventResponse
from("activemq:queue:" + getQueue())
        // note here unmarshall is manual but also use Jsonb
        .bean(EventUnmarshaller.class) // use class form so that Camel will cache the bean
            .setProperty("skipAck", simple("${body.skipAck}"))
        .bean(SomeFieldValidator.class)
        .bean(ConfigDetailsEnricher.class)
        .split(body(), (oldExchange, newExchange) -> { // reduce each new EventResponse into the result list
            if (oldExchange == null) {
                // the first time we aggregate we only have the new exchange,
                // so we just return it
                return newExchange;
            }
            List<EventResponse> list = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
            EventResponse newElement = newExchange.getIn().getBody(EventResponse.class);
            list.add(newElement);
            oldExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
            return oldExchange;
        })
            .to("direct:individual")
        .end() // end split
.to("direct:replyRoute");

// split route, all beans here only deals with one EventSpecificConfig; after all convert to EventResponse
from("direct:individual")
        .filter().method(CriteriaFilter.class)
        .bean(AnotherFieldsTailor.class)
        .bean(RestOperationEnricher.class)
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${body.restOperation.name} != 'DELETE'"))
            .bean(NonDeleteOperationEventFieldsTailor.class)
        .end()
        .bean(HttpMethodEnricher.class)
        .bean(TokenRetriever.class) // call oauth endpoint; as here a cache is used for token so have to use a bean. Set token to EventSpecificConfig
        // inject url into header here; as when reaching "toD()", the body already has change to type Event, not EventSpecificConfig
        .bean(EventApiConfiguration.class) // after this step, body is already new event(PUT, POST) / null(DELETE)
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${body} != null"))
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jsonb)
            .endChoice()
        .end()
        .toD("${header.url}", 10) // only cache at most 10 urls
        ;

from("direct:replyRoute") // list of EventResponse
        .bean(EventResponsesProcessor.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Reply: " + simple("${body}"))
        .setHeader("from", constant("MYAPP"));
```

And for the api configuration:

```java
@Handler
void configure(EventSpecificConfig eventSpecificConfig, Exchange exchange) {
    ConfigDetail configDetail = eventSpecificConfig.getConfigDetail();
    String httpMethodUpperCase = eventSpecificConfig.getHttpMethod().getMethodName();
    SubscriptionEvent newEvent = eventSpecificConfig.getNewEvent();
    Message message = exchange.getIn();
    message.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + eventSpecificConfig.getToken());
    message.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, httpMethodUpperCase);
    message.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    if (HTTP_METHODS_WITH_PATH.contains(httpMethodUpperCase)) {
        message.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, "/" + newEvent.getImsi());
    }
    if (HTTP_METHODS_WITH_BODY.contains(httpMethodUpperCase)) {
        message.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        message.setBody(newEvent);
    } else { // DELETE
        message.setBody(null); // DELETE has no body
        // more logic of setting headers for HTTP query params depending on config values
    }
    message.setHeader("url", configDetail.url()); // toD() has no access to EventSpecificConfig, only header works
}
```

I find out that `choice().when().endchoice().otherwise().endchoice().end()` needs a `to()` in every branch, I cannot `when().setHeader().endchoice()`. So at last I decide to put all this logic into a bean.

And you must use `end()` to end `choice()`, you cannot use `endchoice()`; `endchoice()` is for `when()` and `otherwise()`. Quite misleading.

```java
choice()
    .when(simple("${header.foo} == 'bar'"))
        .to("x")
    .endchoice()
    .otherwise()
        .to("y")
    .endchoice()
.end()
```

I thought `endchoice()` is on the same level as `choice()`. Why it's not named like `endbranch()`?