# Apache Camel: how to conditionally set header and set body with toD() without marshal too early?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I just realized that `choice()` in Apache Camel is for dynamic routing, so every `choice()` needs a `to()`. It is not equivalent to `if` in Java.

But, does that mean that I cannot conditionally set header to my camel exchange?

I want to do something like this:

```java
from("direct:eventHttpChoice") // last step returns a composite POJO with config details and the actual message and token, let's call it MyCompositePojo
    .log(....) // I see this message in log
    .setHeader("Authorization", simple("Bearer ${body.token}"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("${body.httpMethod.name}"))
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${body.httpMethod.name} in 'PUT,DELETE'"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, simple("${body.newEvent.number}"))
        .endChoice()
    .end()
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${body.httpMethod.name} in 'POST,PUT'"))
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .setBody(simple("${body.newEvent}")).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jsonb) // marshall here as toD() needs InputStream; and I believe here it converts my message to MyMessagePojo, the actual payload to send
        .endChoice()
        .otherwise() // DELETE
            .when(simple("${body.configDetail.http.deleteSomeField} == 'true' && ${body.newEvent.someField} != null && ${body.newEvent.someField} != ''"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("someField=${body.newEvent.someField}&operationId=${body.newEvent.operationId}"))
            .endChoice()
            .otherwise()
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("operationId=${body.newEvent.operationId}"))
            .endChoice()
        .endChoice()
    .end()
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Sending to this url: ${body.configDetail.url}") // I don't see this log
    .toD("${body.configDetail.url}", 10) // only cache at most 10 urls; I still need MyCompositePojo here
```

But I receive error:

> 2022-12-14 10:44:49,213 ERROR [org.apa.cam.pro.err.DefaultErrorHandler] (Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsConsumer[my.queue]) Failed delivery for (MessageId: A9371D97F55900C-0000000000000001 on ExchangeId: A9371D97F55900C-0000000000000001). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: configDetail on null due to: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: configDetail not found on bean: [B@330cd22d of type: [B on the exchange: Exchange[A9371D97F55900C-0000000000000001]

MyCompositePojo has this field. But I don't know where I get it wrong.

If you think I am doing `marshall()` too early, but if not like this, how can I set body? Because without `.marshal()` I see this error:

> 2022-12-14 12:25:41,772 ERROR [org.apa.cam.pro.err.DefaultErrorHandler] (Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - JmsConsumer[page.large.sm.provisioning.events.online]) Failed delivery for (MessageId: 65FF01C9FC61E66-0000000000000011 on ExchangeId: 65FF01C9FC61E66-0000000000000011). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: configDetail on null due to: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: configDetail not found on bean: MyPojo{xxx=xxx, ...} of type: com.example.MyPojo on the exchange: Exchange[65FF01C9FC61E66-0000000000000011]

So, it means without `.marshal()`, it is changing the body to my MessagePojo; but I don't want it, I just need body to be part of my original body, and when it's HTTP DELETE, I don't want to set body. And, later in the route, I still need my composite pojo. I mean, I want to set the HTTP body and only conditionally, I don't want to change the exchange body.

So, how to conditionally set header and send to dynamic URL and set body?

Comment: But I don't want to use the body multiple times; I want to use the body content before marshall() step in a later step.

Comment: At last I use a bean to put all the `choice()` logic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74549659/which-eip-to-use-retrieve-config-by-message-content-mapping-filtering-and-oau/74595769#74595769

Comment: sorry, wrong copy/paste. The streaming solution was for another post :-( I therefore delete my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to replace the (Camel) choice logic by a custom (Java) processor.

```
from("direct:demo")
    .process( e -> setDynamicUri(e) );
    .toD("${headers.nextUri}");


private void setDynamicUri(Exchange e) {
    String httpMethod = e.getMessage().getHeader("...", String.class);
    String endpointUrl = ( Arrays.asList("PUT", "DELETE").contains(httpMethod) ? "url1" : "url2" );
    e.getMessage().setHeader("nextUri", endpointUrl);
}
```

Comment: BTW: The processor being called **at runtime**, you can put a breakpoint in it, and easily follow the message flow :-)

Comment: Yes...  at last I use a bean, basically same thing.

Comment: At last I have to use a bean, so this processor approach is basically the same; I set header and url and body in the bean dynamically.